# Слетел перевод текста ссылок на RSS-ленту

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, rss

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @PashaPash, кажется, вы поторопились с покраснением. Там ещё хинты помимо этого.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ не все слова утвердили =/

Comment: уже вроде бы все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12317

> Лента участника

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12326

> Лента новых вопросов с меткой [$tagNames$]

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12348

> Лента последних активных вопросов с меткой [$tagNames$]

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12349

> Лента вопросов за неделю

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12321

> Лента новых вопросов

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12346

> Лента вопросов за месяц

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12344

> Лента популярных вопросов

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12335

> Лента вопросов с наивысшим рейтингом с меткой [$tagNames$]

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12340

> Лента конкурсных вопросов с меткой [$tagNames$]

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12315

> Лента конкурсных вопросов